# Entity Connection String Via ini File

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

How would one store the connection string of entity framework and call it from ini file. I was able to do this easy using ado and vb.net but the entity connection string is allot different all I want to store in the ini file is the server username and password. In  A secure folder away from the application code.

This is what i am connecting with in my app config

```
<add name="DeliveryEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Delivery.csdl|res://*/Delivery.ssdl|res://*Delivery.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DAVID-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Delivery;user id=sa;password=;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Password emitted for reasons

Comment: Is it Code First? Model First?

Comment: @haim770 if you mean by that I create the edmx fILE i persume thats model first

Comment: Show your current connection-string.

Comment: @haim770 added the connection string to edit

Comment: One last question: is your `DeliveryContainer` derives from `ObjectContext` or `DbContext`

Comment: @haim770 just the standard way when you go add new edmx file no modifications made

Comment: It depends on EF and VS versions.

Comment: @haim770 EF 3.5 cant change as is legacy system @ Visual studio 2010 I want to just store username password and server in a ini file cant be this difficult is it something for the good old days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your current connection string to not include the username and password.

Then, change your `DeliveryContainer` to accept your own `DbConnection` in it's constructor:

```
Public Partial Class DeliveryContainer
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New(conn As DbConnection)
        MyBase.New(conn, True)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("name=DeliveryContainer")
    End Sub

    '....
End Class
```

Now your have to construct your own `EntityConnection` using the information stored in your INI file:

```
Public Shared Function GetConnection() As EntityConnection
    Dim dbServerName = iniConf("dbServerName")
    Dim dbDatabaseName = iniConf("dbDatabaseName")
    Dim dbUserId = iniConf("DbUserId")
    Dim dbUserPassword = iniConf("DbUserPassword")

    Dim configCs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DeliveryEntities").ConnectionString
    Dim entityCsBuilder = New EntityConnectionStringBuilder(configCs)

    Dim sqlCsBuilder = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(entityCsBuilder.ProviderConnectionString)

    ' Inject your username and password from the INI file (if exists)
    If dbUserId IsNot Nothing AndAlso dbUserPassword IsNot Nothing Then
        sqlCsBuilder.UserID = dbUserId
        sqlCsBuilder.Password = dbUserPassword
    End If

    sqlCsBuilder.DataSource = dbServerName
    sqlCsBuilder.InitialCatalog = dbDatabaseName

    entityCsBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlCsBuilder.ConnectionString

    Return New EntityConnection(entityCsBuilder.ConnectionString)
End Function
```

When creating a new `DeliveryContainer`:

```
Dim context = New DeliveryContainer(GetConnection())
```

Comment: where would I place the code in the second part also should have mentioned im a vb.net user think i did in post tags

Comment: and also is it possible to store the sql server as well in ini file thats the three things i need to store

Comment: I wrapped the custom `EntityConnection` creation in an helper function.

Comment: @haaim70 thank you just seeing this now is their anyway to parse the old sql username and password out just my tech support are used to seeing one line like this CONNECTION_STRING=Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=skechersDelivery;Data Source=DAVID-PC\SQLEXPRESS;

Comment: hats off to this guy excellent didnt here from him for a while came back to this first thing morning

Comment: Thanks. As per your question, do you mean you're using Integrated Security and don't have a username and password in your connection string?

Comment: I need to check with the boss on that I beleive so at till level

Comment: well on the normal connection string yes its integrated I didnt no entity gave you the option of integrated SO I gather I best keep to intergrated.

Comment: I added an `If` to check if username and password exists in your INI.

Comment: @Hhaim770 what should i do though in my context file when I paste in your code it says under the helper create a stub ?

Comment: Where did you place the `GetConnection()` method?

Comment: haim770 within a custom class is that not correct ?

Comment: Yes it is correct, is has to be available globally. Did you make it `Shared`?

Comment: yes but i create the deliverycontainer file then it asks for new stubs to be created for the two new methods in the code ?

Comment: i added code to your edit see from db notes downards

Comment: I got it working  but what happens if connection string changes to integrated security is their something else i need to add to the settings in app.config thanks so much budy

Comment: If you're changing to integrated security and you INI doesn't contain username and password, then the class won't try to inject them into the connection string.

Comment: THANK U THANK U THANK U THANK U ALL WORKING AMAING I NEW HOW TO DO THIS IN C# BUT VB AVATES ME SOMETIMES

Comment: one final thing is their an easy way to test if a connection is successful or not? obv when you declare on a new it would fail over if no setting in the app config file to being with ?